# NetBeans Maven: ClassCastException - RestEasy vs Jersey

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, resteasy, classcastexception

As my title says, I believe the issue is with classloading, and the fact that my application is trying to cast a jersey-core class to resteasy. Below is the code that triggers it, as well as the error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.3/enterprise/modules/ext/rest/jersey-core-1.13.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/hwng/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/pics-client/branding/target/netbeans_clusters/pics_client/modules/ext/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api-2.3.5.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:126)
at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:96)
```

Code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
    IRoutesService client = ProxyFactory.create(IRoutesService.class,
            "http://localhost:8080/rest/routeservice/");
    client.postRoute(txtRouteName.getText());
}
```

Now, my NetBeans Platform module (maven) has dependency on the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The myapp-api is a jar that is located also on the server and is used to interact with the service. The POM for the myapp-api has the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All in all, I am not sure why NetBeans is even remotely trying to look at jersey-core when I don't seem to have any reference to it. Any help or advise is appreciated.

I Right Clicked on my RouteTopComponent and looked at the runtime classpath and can clearly see jersey-core in there. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this was a silly mistake of a newbie. I have assumed that pressing F6 in NetBeans (to run) will automatically launch my NetBeans Platform Application (mavenized); however, it wasn't launching what it should. It was launching my TopComponent in a new instance of NetBeans Platform (hence all the Jersey classes loaded).

All I had to do was to actually right click the my-application-app and choose run for it to actually launch my application correctly.

Perhaps this will be useful to anyone who ever makes the same assumption as me and tries to run file directly.